# Need to get a count for a numeric range between 2000-2500 in bash

Tags: regex, bash, unix, grep

Need a count of latency range between 2000 to 2500 using grep/egrep, 
consider all the contents in a log file.

I tried the following : 
          `Zgrep "/Api1\|Api2" log.gz|grep '"latency":[2000-2500]'|wc -l` but  getting random counts.

```
"Api1":"some", "latency":1000,
"Api1":"some", "latency":1000, 
"Api2":"some", "latency":1000,
"Api1":"some", "latency":1000,
"Api2":"some", "latency":2100,
"Api1":"some", "latency":2400, 
"Api2":"some", "latency":2400,
"Api1":"some", "latency":2500
```

output:

```
count 4
"Api2":"some", "latency":2100,
"Api1":"some", "latency":2400, 
"Api2":"some", "latency":2400,
"Api1":"some", "latency":2500
```

Comment: You should show us what you tried

Comment: @ThomasAyoub I tried the following :  Zgrep "/Api1\|Api2" log.gz|grep "latency:[2000-2500]"|wc -l but getting random counts.

Comment: What is your desired output for the input you've shown?

Comment: @TomFenech I need to get output like: 

      count: 4
      "Api2":"some", "latency":2100,
      "Api1":"some", "latency":2400, 
      "Api2":"some", "latency":2400,
      "Api1":"some", "latency":2500

Comment: How damn do you expect your `grep` to get the lines having the format `"latency":` if your pattern is `latency:` -- you have missed the double quotes in the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo could use awk

```
awk -F, '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ( $i ~ /latency/ ) { split($i,arry,":");if ( arry[2] >= 2000 && arry[2] <= 2500 ) { print $0;cnt++ } } } } END { print "Count "cnt }' filename
```

Separate each line in filename with the separator "," then loop through each field looking the the text "latency" and split the 2nd field further using ":" putting the results in the array "arry" We then concentrate on the second element "arry[2]" and check that it is between 2000 and 2500. If it is then increment the variable "cnt" by 1. We finally print cnt.

Comment: Its not working, Nothing is printing on the terminal.

Comment: Worked fine for me when I use it with your sample data.

Comment: I've amended to print the lines found.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.  I've a large log file, its difficult to finding the position of particular key i.e. "latency". Is there any way to make the position dynamic? i mean search for that word and get the position then split and do other actions.

Comment: I have amended to check each field for the text "latency"

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
grep -E '"latency":(2[0-4][0-9][0-9]|2500)'
```

The `2[0-4][0-9][0-9]` part matches any number that has `2` thousands, `0` to `4` hundreds and any value for tens and units (`00` to `99`).

The `2500` part matches only the value `2500`, of course.

The two are combined using `|` that means "alternation": either part could match. The parentheses around them are required to limit the scope of the alternation meta-character. Without parentheses we need to duplicate the `"latency":` part after the `|`; otherwise `2500` can match in other contexts too.

In the code you posted the output of `grep` is sent to `wc -l` to count how many lines were found. `grep -c` can do the count for you and return the count instead of the matched lines:

```
grep -c -E '"latency":(2[0-4][0-9][0-9]|2500)'
```

#### Why your regex doesn't work

The character class `[2000-2500]` matches any of the characters present between the square brackets that do not have special meaning.

Inside a character class (`[...]`) there are several characters with special meaning:

- `^`, only if it is the first character in the character class, negates the meaning of the clas; it means "any character **not present** in the class"; if you need it to represent itself then don't put it the first character in the class;
- `-`, only if it **is not** the first or the last character in the character class, it used to specify a range. `0-2` in your case means "any character between and including `0` and `2`"; `[0-2]` is the same as `[012]` (or `[201]` or `[120]` etc. because the order of characters in a character class doesn't matter); if you need it to represent itself then put it the first (after `^` if it's a negating class) or the last character in the class;
- `]` is used to close the class; if you need it to represent itself then escape it using `\`.

All in all, `[2000-2500]` is the same as `[0125]` and it matches any of `0`, `1`, `2` or `5`.

Comment: Looks like the OP wanted a count too, so maybe it'd be better to use awk.

Comment: @TomFenech The `| wc -l` part from the OP's code still stands. Or they can use `grep -c` to get the count instead of the matching lines. Or you can write an answer that uses `awk` :-)

Comment: I had something like this once, where the number was a day number (starting from 1/1/1970), but requirements specified using a regexp to identify weekdays. Challenge: develop a regexp that can do div-by-7. I still have the scar on my forehead where my head hit the keyboard...

Comment: Just one thing to note: ']' is also a special char in a character class too. If you want to  include a ']' as one of the chars, it must be the first one.

Comment: @SusanW you are right, I forgot about it. It can also be escaped.